# Agregar tipografía en aplicación Java Swing

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

¿Cómo hacer para que se descargue un tipo de fuente de letra automáticamente al descargar un programa en Java?

Estoy haciendo un programa con Java Swing, NetBeans. En el diseño utilizo una fuente específica (Montserrat). Si el programa lo está usando otra persona en una computadora que no tiene descargada esa fuente, ¿cómo haría para que en el programa aparezca ese estilo de letra? Agradezco mucho su colaboración, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un instalador, en el cual contenga los archivos de tu programa y dentro de estos archivos pongas la fuente que utilizaste para que la instale.

### https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiFffmx6-uM

En ese video tutorial te enseñan a como crear un instalador.